# Can't install the latest version of the Linux headers

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I tried all the solutions given here in the website, but I am still unable to locate and install the kali linux headers. I have linux 4.6.0 version. Here is my problem:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked which packages _are_ available matching the `linux-headers-*` glob?  I think `apt-cache` is the tool for this, but I will admit that it has been a few years since I used an `apt`-based system

Answer (score 2):

The Linux-headers packages change their name quite often, as newer and newer kernel versions come out.

Start with an `apt-get update` command to update your package lists.

Then, with an

```
apt-cache search linux-headers-
```

command get a list of the kernel headers package which are currently existing in the package repositories. You will get a list of packages. Find the most sympathic for you (ideally, the highest version), and finally install it with the `apt-get install linux-headers-4.56.76-kali-amd64` command (the last two part of the version numbers are only example).

Comment: Hello thanks for your help ! i did what u commented exactly but when i searched to know the package list it's show nothing ... here is a photo http://prntscr.com/f0c4re

Comment: and also i did the same commands and still the same problem :- http://prntscr.com/f0cai2